# How to access store in different component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reducers

So I have a search bar where I store the queries with redux, which seems to work. I am now trying to access that query in a results component which I am going to use to display the results of the query.

I have tried using MapStateToProps and then just calling {this.props.query} in my Results component, but that doesn't get the query changes from the search bar.

Store creation:

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { userReducer } from "./redux/reducers/user-reducer";
import { searchReduer } from "./redux/reducers/search-reducer"
import logger from "redux-logger";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

const store = createStore(
  combineReducers({
      user: userReducer,
      query: searchReducer,
  }),
  {},
  applyMiddleware(logger)
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Search:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import elasticsearchUtility from "../utilities/elastic-search-utility";

const styles = theme => ({
    container: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        flexDirection: 'row',
    },
    margin: {
        margin: theme.spacing.unit,
    },
    cssLabel: {
        color: 'white',
        '&$cssFocused': {
            color: 'white',
        },
    },
    cssFocused: {
    },
    cssUnderline: {
        color: 'white',
    },
    cssOutlinedInput: {
        '&$cssFocused $notchedOutline': {
            borderColor: 'white',
        },
    },
    notchedOutline: {
        borderWidth: '1px',
        borderColor: 'white !important'
    },
});

class Search extends Component{
    state = {
        searchQuery: ""
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        elasticsearchUtility.startClient();
    }

    onChange = event => {
        this.props.updateQuery(event.target.value);
    };

    render() {
        const {searchQuery, classes} = this.props;

        return (
            <div className={this.props.classes.container}>
                <TextField
                    fullWidth={true}
                    className={classes.margin}
                    InputLabelProps={{
                        classes: {
                            root: classes.cssLabel,
                            focused: classes.cssFocused,
                        },
                    }}
                    InputProps={{
                        classes: {
                            root: classes.cssOutlinedInput,
                            focused: classes.cssFocused,
                            notchedOutline: classes.notchedOutline,
                        },
                    }}
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                    label="Service search"
                    variant="outlined"
                    id="custom-css-outlined-input"
                    value={searchQuery}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        query: state.searchQuery
    }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        updateQuery: (query) => {
            dispatch(search(query))
        }
    }
};

function search(value) {
    return {type: "SEARCH", value};
}

Search.propTypes = {
    classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(
    connect(
        mapStateToProps,
        mapDispatchToProps
    )(Search)
);
```

Search-results:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import connect from "react-redux/es/connect/connect";

class SearchResults extends Component {

    render() {
        console.log(this.props.query);
        return (
            <div>
            <h1>Test + {this.props.query}</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { query: state.searchQuery };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SearchResults)
```

Search-reducer:

```
export const initialQuery = '';

export const searchReducer = (state = initialQuery, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case "SEARCH":
            return action.value;
        default:
            return state;
    }

};
```

In search-results, {this.props.query} is always undefined, even though I can see the state.query changing when I input text in the search bar. I am assuming I am misunderstanding something about Redux, but I'm not super sure what, since I am able to update the searchQuery properly in my "Search" component.

Comment: store code ? where you are passing reducer to store. post that as well.

Comment: It looks like you are using `react-redux`, but cannot see you using `Provider` for initiate your store. if you can paste this part of codes, will help to distinguish the issue. https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/quick-start#provider

Comment: @AnilKumar updated.

Comment: @tim updated, see above.

Comment: it is like it is already solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're mixing up `query` and `searchQuery` in a few places.

```
  combineReducers({
      user: userReducer,
      query: searchReducer,
  }),
```

You're setting `state.query` as your global query object, but both of your `mapStateToProps` are trying to access `state.searchQuery`.

Also, in `Search`'s render, you have `const {searchQuery, classes} = this.props;`, but again, `mapStateToProps` is mapping `state.searchQuery` to `props.query`, so `props.searchQuery` is undefined.

Seems like you just have to make sure you're using the correct mapping, or pick either `query` or `searchQuery` and use it both in global state and in props.

Comment: You are a lifesaver. I have been debugging for hours and totally missed that, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use :

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
return { query: state.query.searchQuery };
}
```